# In this how do i set color for the label while generating a pdf

Tags: java, pdf

```
private static PdfPTable generateCell(PdfPTable table, String label, String value
        , Font labelFont, Font valueFont, int padding, int colSpan
        , int rowSpan, int hAlign, int vAlign, float[] borders, Boolean completeRow) {
    Chunk receiveLabel = new Chunk(label);
    receiveLabel.setFont(labelFont);
    Chunk receiveValue = new Chunk(value);
    //receiveValue.setUnderline(0.1f, -2f); //0.1 thick, -2 y-location
    receiveValue.setFont(valueFont);
    Phrase phraseReceive = new Phrase();
    phraseReceive.add(receiveLabel);
    //phrase.add(whiteSpace);
    phraseReceive.add(receiveValue);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phraseReceive);
    cell.setPadding(padding);
    cell.setColspan(colSpan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowSpan);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(hAlign);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(vAlign);
    cell.setBorderWidthLeft(borders[0]);
    cell.setBorderWidthRight(borders[1]);
    cell.setBorderWidthTop(borders[2]);
    cell.setBorderWidthBottom(borders[3]);
    table.addCell(cell);
    if(completeRow) {
        table.completeRow();
    }
    return table;
}
```

Here i need to set color for the label can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

you may refer this to set color for the label in your code.

```
Chunk receiveLabel = new Chunk(label,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD, new Color(255, 0, 0)));
```